# Iterate on PHP variable (list/array) then output the index based on its value

Tags: php, loops, indexing

Using the following example in PHP:

```
$priv['PAGE_A'] = 11;
$priv['PAGE_B'] = 22;
$priv['PAGE_C'] = 33;
$priv['PAGE_D'] = 44;
```

1) I would like to iterate on the 4 values in $priv. Would 'foreach' be the correct way to do it?

2) If the value is higher than a given number, I would like to echo the index of this value. Not sure how to do it. The comparaison must be INT (not string).

Ex. using "30" it would output:

```
PAGE_C
PAGE_D
```

Is it possible? Or maybe I am not using the correct container for what I'm trying to do ?

PS. How would you call the type of "$priv" in this example ? An array ? An indexed variable ? A dictionary ? A list ?

Thank you.

Comment: `foreach ($priv as $key => $value) {` is the way to start, then evaluate `$value` and echo `$key`, and yes it is an array

Comment: To be precise, $priv is an associative array, or a hash map, or a key-value store, just to differentiate from an indexed array where keys are numeric offsets.

Comment: Thanks to everyone who replied. I got exactly what I'm looking for. I appreciate all your help. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

basically:

```
<?php
function foo($var){

    $priv['PAGE_A'] = 11;
    $priv['PAGE_B'] = 22;
    $priv['PAGE_C'] = 33;
    $priv['PAGE_D'] = 44;

    $out='';
    foreach ($priv as $k=>$v){

        if ($v >$var){
            $out .= $k.'<br>';
        }
    }
  return $out;
}
echo foo('30');
```

demo: http://codepad.viper-7.com/GNX7Gf

Answer (score 1):

Just create an array with the letters to iterate over.

```
$letters = array('A','B','C','D');
for($i=0;$i<count($letters);$i++) {
    if($priv['PAGE_' . $letters[$i]] > /*value*/) {
        echo $priv['PAGE_' . $letters[$i]];
    }
}
```

$priv is an array.

Also, it's not too clear to me what you are exactly trying to do. Are you trying to echo the value of the array element if it's greater than a constant value?

Comment: how does this produce "PAGE_C
PAGE_D"  based on 30 ??

Comment: I am altogether a bit confused as to what he is trying to do. I thought he was trying to echo the element's value rather than its name.

Answer (score 0):

We could do it using PHP builtin array functions. Its good to use builtin functions if possible in case of performance.

*array_walk* will do the trick for you. In this case *$priv* is an associative PHP array. Following is the one line script that will do what you want to achieve:

```
$input          = 30;
$priv['PAGE_A'] = 11;
$priv['PAGE_B'] = 22;
$priv['PAGE_C'] = 33;
$priv['PAGE_D'] = 44;

array_walk($priv, function($value, $key, $input){ if($value > $input) echo $key . '<br>';}, $input);
```